# register activex control at the time of installation of application

Tags: c#, activex

Can We register activex control during installation of software ?
i developed application which require to register activex control . so how to do it during user install application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a dll or exe or vbs file which contains the program to register your activex control.

Right click on your setup project >> click view and choose custom actions

on left side >> under custom actions you will see install folder

right click on it and click on add custom aciton

under application folder choose exe or dll or vbs which you created at the start

Comment: right now i dont have any.. but for that you can create a win32 project under other languages >> visual c++ 
you can google and will find many ways to do that